# how to get specific text on the web?

Tags: python

i need text from this web "https://turnbackhoax.id/2022/09/27/salah-artikel-berjudul-optimis-menang-pemilu-2024-puan-kita-bersama-wong-licik/" but just after "[narasi] :" of course i need in many link

i try this code :

```
 isiberita = []

urllib3.disable_warnings()
for link in link1:

    req = http.request("GET", link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.data,'html.parser')
    for j in soup.find('p',text="[NARASI]:\n").nextSibling:
    isiberita.append(j.get_text)
```

but it not working

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for .find is

```py
soup.find('p', attrs={'sub-tag': 'class name'})
```